# Google Books API not enabled? Doesnt

Tags: php, json, api, symfony, google-api

I'm doing a little app doing some researched about title books using Google Books API.

If I do it without a APIkey it works like [this](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=the%20hunger%20games) (click please, to see the response).

There is the first problem:
I'm doing a php (symfony 3) `HTTP 'GET'` petition... and I'm receiving this... but I don't know it's a `String` and not a `json` so, I tried to `encode` and `decode` this.. and nothing works.. it's still being `String`

Any idea?

For the another hand I thought that maybe It's because I am not using an Google APIkey so, [I did it with the APIkey](https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:the%20hunger%20games&key=AIzaSyAN638WbYe1vOfGya989p7ZbfXnPzBLfkg) but I receive this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Books API has not been used in project 590805047596 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/books/overview?project=590805047596 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/books/overview?project=590805047596"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Books API has not been used in project 590805047596 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/books/overview?project=590805047596 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

But I activated it many days ago.. and I tried to create another one too..
so...

- Why I cannot convert `String` to `json` in `php`?
- Why appears like I haven't permissions with my Google APIkey?

Any solution for any problem?

**Thanks a lot to every reader!**
**Have a nice day.**

**Victor**

Comment: Did you visit the link to the Google API Console provided in the error message and check that the API is enabled?

Comment: mh.. no way! When you want to enable Google API keys... the Book API Key doesn't appear so, there is no way. I just clicked: Create project API

Comment: Try going to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/books-json.googleapis.com/overview?project=590805047596. When you land on that page, you should see an "Enable" link at the top next to the "Google Books API" header. Click that link to enable your API.