# Books API has not been used in project ******** before or it is disabled. Error code 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I'm trying to migrate to Google Identity Services. When I log a user in and try to get info from their Google Books account I get "error code 403. Books API has not been used in project ****** before or it is disabled"

I checked the project number that was being used before I tried to migrate to Google Identity Services and the project number is totally different from the one stated in the error, and I definitely have the Book API enabled.

I use the following scripts in the react index.html page:

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" async defer></script>`

`script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>`

**App.js**

```
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import CreatePost from "./pages/CreatePost";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Logout from "./pages/Logout";

import "./App.css";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(isAuth);
  }, [isAuth]);

  var tokenClient;

  function gisInit() {
    tokenClient = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
      client_id: *********,
      scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books',
    });
  }

  function gapiStart() {
    window.gapi.client.init({
    }).then(function() {
      // fetch the Books API
      window.gapi.client.load('books', 'v1');
      
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log('books loaded');
      gisInit()
    }, function(reason) {
      console.log('Error: ' + reason.result.error.message);
    });
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    window.gapi.load('client', gapiStart);  
  })
  
  return (
    <>
    <nav>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      <Link to="/createpost">Create</Link>
      { !isAuth ? <Link to="/login">Login</Link> : <Link to="/logout">Logout</Link> }
    </nav>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
      <Route path="/createpost" element={ <CreatePost /> } />
      <Route path="/login" element={ <Login setIsAuth={ setIsAuth } /> } />
      <Route path="/logout" element={ <Logout setIsAuth={ setIsAuth } /> } />
    </Routes>
    </>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Login.js**

```
import {auth, provider} from "../firebase-config";
import { signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

// var url = 'books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves/4/volumes?fields=totalItems, items(id, volumeInfo/title, volumeInfo/authors, volumeInfo/publishedDate, volumeInfo/publisher, volumeInfo/industryIdentifiers, volumeInfo/imageLinks)'; //A local page

function getData(access_token){
    // console.log("token " + access_token);
    window.gapi.client.setToken({"access_token":access_token});
    const fetchUserData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        
        const request = window.gapi.client.request({
            'method': 'GET',
            // 'path': 'books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves/4/volumes?fields=totalItems, items(id, volumeInfo/title, volumeInfo/authors, volumeInfo/publishedDate, volumeInfo/publisher, volumeInfo/industryIdentifiers, volumeInfo/imageLinks)'
            'path': 'books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves/4/volumes?fields=totalItems, items(id)',
        });

        // // Execute the API request.
        request.execute( function(response) {
            // const obj = response.result;
            resolve(response);
            
            reject("Error");          
    
        });   
    });
        
    fetchUserData.then((value)=>{
    console.log(value);         
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    });
}

function Login({ setIsAuth }){

    useEffect(()=>{
        signInWithGoogle();
    });

    let navigate = useNavigate();
    provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books");

    const signInWithGoogle = () =>{
        signInWithPopup(auth, provider).then((result)=>{
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
            const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
            let token = credential.accessToken;

            if(result.user){
                setIsAuth(true);
                getData(token);
                console.log(result.user.displayName);
                navigate("/");
            }
            
        }).catch((error)=>{
            if(error.code === 'auth/popup-closed-by-user'){
                setIsAuth(false);
                navigate("/");
            }
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
        <p>Logging in...</p>
                       
        </>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

What do I have to do to be able to use the right project?

If I swap out the firebase auth and just use the Google Identity Services auth then I can get the information back from the signed in users Google Books account. Looking at the browser network tab the "authorization: Bearer" is the same.

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

// var url = 'books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves/4/volumes?fields=totalItems, items(id, volumeInfo/title, volumeInfo/authors, volumeInfo/publishedDate, volumeInfo/publisher, volumeInfo/industryIdentifiers, volumeInfo/imageLinks)'; //A local page

function getData(){
    const fetchUserData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        
        const request = window.gapi.client.request({
            'method': 'GET',
            'path': 'books/v1/mylibrary/bookshelves/4/volumes?fields=totalItems, items(id, volumeInfo/title, volumeInfo/authors, volumeInfo/publishedDate, volumeInfo/publisher, volumeInfo/industryIdentifiers, volumeInfo/imageLinks)'
        });

        // // Execute the API request.
        request.execute( function(response) {
          // const obj = response.result;
          resolve(response);
        
          reject("Error");          

        });   
    });
    
    fetchUserData.then((value)=>{
        console.log(value);      
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)//error shows an empty array when controller abort called
    });    
}

function Login({ setIsAuth }){
    var tokenClient;
    var access_token;
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    function getToken(){
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
    }

    function initGis(){
        tokenClient = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: *******,
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books',
            callback: (tokenResponse) => {
              access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
              if(access_token !== undefined){
                setIsAuth(true);
                getData();
                navigate("/");
              }  
            },//end of callback:
            
        });
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        initGis();
        getToken();  
    });

    return (
        <>
        <p>Logging in...</p>
        </>             
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: You added that swapping out Firebase auth resolved this error, do you need to use Firebase Authentication for this functionality? Have you also used the link included in the error trace ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623369/)) to confirm the API is enabled? Moreover, which providers are configured in your Firebase console?

Comment: @ErnestoC Thanks you. I suppose it's not imperative to use Firebase Authentication but it would be nice. Yes I clicked on the error trace link and it takes me to the Google Cloud Platform Console. As I said the Books API is enabled and I had been successfully using it before I tried to migrate to Google Identity Services. In my Firebase console I have the Google Authentication provider enabled. I looked at the firebase project and that is the project number in the error so even though I provide the client_id from the project I was using before it's trying to use the firebase account project.

Comment: @ErnestoC I've just watched a [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/Bj15-6rBHQw?t=350) where the person signs the user in with the old google auth2, gets the token, signs the user in with firebase. The old google auth2 is being deprecated therefore the migration. If I can sign the user in manually without another pop up it will resolve the issue. ```const credential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(token)```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.googleauthprovider#example                 


```const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
const result = await signInWithCredential(credential);```

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do to solve the problem is when making the firebase project select the Google Cloud Platform project from the dropdown list.